# Parsing Malformed HTML in Python gives index out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, beautifulsoup

Here is the part of HTML that I am trying to parse:

```
<div class="syntax-container">
<h2>Official Syntax</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <strong>Syntax: </strong> </p>
  <pre>text-align: start | end | left | right | center | justify</pre>
  </li>
  ...and so on.
```

This is my Python code:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
propSyntax  = ''.join(soup.select('.syntax-container pre')[0].findAll(text=True))
propSyntax  = propSyntax.strip()
propSyntax  = '<h2>Syntax</h2>' + '<p><pre>' + propSyntax + '</pre></p>'
```

This is the error I get:

```
propSyntax  = ''.join(soup.select('.syntax-container pre')[0].findAll(text=True))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand that the error is because of the extra `</p>` after `</strong>` but I don't know how to get rid of this error and parse the data properly. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prettify? If not Try:

```
soup.prettify()
```

or

```
soup.prettify().select('.syntax-container pre')[0].findAll(text=True)
```

Comment: I think this created an infinite loop because the nothing has happened in the console after I updated the code.

Comment: try `propSyntax  = "".join(soup.select(' pre')[0].findAll(text=True))`

Comment: I have done that and it works but I need a more general solutions because the tags will be changing vary frequently.